# HTML form submit after javascript check Node Js req.body content will undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got a problem, when my html Form submit, Node Js app.post{} will get correct value. However, when I use onsubmit in the form, and check value before submit. Then Node Js app.post req.body will display undefinded.

Original code:
html:

```
<form id="formLogin" role="form" action="/loginprocess" method="POST">
  <input id="textEmail" name="username">
  <input id="textPwd" name="pwd">
  <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">login</button>
</form>
```

node.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/loginprocess', function(req, res) {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var pwd = req.body.pwd;

    console.log("username=" + username);  //correct value
    console.log("pwd=" + pwd);            //correct value


});
```

however I want check value that input in form then submit, therefore, I update the form code like below:

html:

```
<form id="formLogin" role="form" action="/loginprocess" method="POST" onsubmit="return checkLoginInfo()">
  <input id="textEmail" name="username">
  <input id="textPwd" name="pwd">
  <button type="submit" id="btnLogin">login</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkLoginInfo() {
    var username = document.getElementById("textEmail").value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("textPwd").value;

    if ((username.length > 0) && (pwd.length > 0)) {
      console.log("yes");
     } else {
      console.log("no");
      return false;
     }
}
</script>
```

my node js:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     
  extended: true
}));

app.post('/loginprocess', function(req, res) {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var pwd = req.body.pwd;

    console.log("username=" + username);  //undefined
    console.log("pwd=" + pwd);            //undefined


});
```

Comment: Where's your submit verification function?

Comment: after `console.log("yes");` try adding  `return;`

Comment: I had add return after console.log("yes"); but still get undefined from req.body.username and pwd

Answer (score 0):

***Updated.***

Since you have updated the question, i would suggest you this:

```
onsubmit="return checkLoginInfo(this)"  <!-- pass the form here -->
```

Now in the js function:

```js
function checkLoginInfo(frm) { // <----get the form here
  var username = document.getElementById("textEmail").value;
  var pwd = document.getElementById("textPwd").value;

  if ((username.length > 0) && (pwd.length > 0)) {
    console.log("yes");
    frm.submit(); // <-----if valid just submit it here.
  } else {
    console.log("no");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had remove some css code for posting this message, and also remove id tag. I had updated my question already.

Comment: I had changed my code like follow your instruction:  onsubmit="return checkLoginInfo(this)"     function checkLoginInfo(frm) {
            var username = document.getElementById("textEmail").value;
            var pwd = document.getElementById("textPwd").value;
            if ((username.length > 0) && (pwd.length > 0)) {
               console.log("yes");
                frm.submit();
            } else {
                console.log("no");
                return false;
            }
        }; still get undefined

Answer (score 0):

If your username and password are correct your function checklogin (in the client js code ) doesn't return anything you'll have to add a return in it

and also add an id to your html inputs ( username and password )

Comment: but then why he says he gets undefined on node server. if id is wrong then , the form is not at submitted.!!

Comment: because the parameters aren't forwarded to the node js, since he is only blocking them, a document.getElementById("formLogin").submit() will do the work, I guess

Comment: hello Hicham Zouarhi, I write like you described but still get undefined.

Comment: @章恩齊 try in your node js code var username = req.body.textEmail;
    var pwd = req.body.textPwd; instead, please